Version solving failed with running Dart commands using asdf in VSCode
I am needing to have multiple versions of Flutter installed so I switched from a regular installation of Flutter/Dart to having two versions of each with asdf. I am able to run Flutter commands without a problem, but attempting to run dart commands is not working and I am having to run them using Flutter (which is deprecated).
I am trying to use my globally installed version of Flutter (latest).
I am attempting this on a MacOS with Sonoma 14.5 and an Apple M1 Pro chip
I ran the command dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs which gave me the following result:
Resolving dependencies in `[path/to/repo]`... 
Because [repo-name] depends on flutter_test from sdk which doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available), version solving failed.

Flutter users should use `flutter pub` instead of `dart pub`.

So I attempted to run the command flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs, and this worked! However I am getting the following warning:
Deprecated. Use `dart run` instead.

This is after I added the following to my paths file:
/Users/myusername/.asdf/installs/flutter/3.22.2-stable/bin
/Users/myusername/.asdf/installs/flutter/3.27.1-stable/bin

as well as the following to my .zshrc file:
export PATH="$PATH":"/Users/myusername/.asdf/installs/flutter/3.22.2-stable/bin"
export PATH="$PATH":"/Users/myusername/.asdf/installs/flutter/3.27.1-stable/bin"

I have all of those paths listed as well in my VSCode settings, under the settings Dart: Sdk Paths and Dart: Flutter Sdk Paths and at the bottom status bar I have ensured that I have the right Flutter/Dart SDKs selected (Currently showing 3.27.1 - Flutter SDK and 3.6.0 (Flutter)Dart SDK)
flutter doctor results:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.27.1, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.3.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.96.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.70.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

Running flutter --version gives me the following:
Flutter 3.27.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 17025dd882 (2 weeks ago) • 2024-12-17 03:23:09 +0900
Engine • revision cb4b5fff73
Tools • Dart 3.6.0 • DevTools 2.40.2

Running dart --version gives me the following:
Dart SDK version: 3.6.0 (stable) (Thu Dec 5 07:46:24 2024 -0800) on "macos_arm64"


try to run this : flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

Try to run this command:
flutter pub get
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

